# Magento 2 category grid not wrapping correctly

Tags: magento2, products, grid-layout

I have a fresh install of Magento 2, and have extended the luma theme, we havent started to edit the category pages as yet, but have noticed the grid doesnt wrap correctly. As you can see from the below, I would be expecting 4 products across on desktop and 2 products across mobile. I have checked other demo sites and they seem to have the same issue ie `[http://shop-by-brand-m2.demo.amasty.com/shop-by-brand-m2/sessions/416219/index.php/women.html][1]`

Desktop

[image]

Mobile
[image]